# How to display a popup after a condition is met using angular 2?

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular2-template

I have this application where you can enter a specific page manually to display from a PDF and I want to display a popup when the user enter a page number higher than the maximum page number.

Here's the code I wrote:

Html :

```
<span>
 <input  class="pageNow" value="{{pageIndex}}" type ="number" #pageId id="choice-page" (keyup.enter) = "getPage(pageId.value);poppup()"/>/ {{documentData?.pageNum}}

<div  class="popup" *ngIf="erreur">
  <span class="popuptext" id="choice-page"> Error:Enter a valid Page number </span>
</div>

</span>
```

The input is where you enter the page number .

Type Script:

```
 public getPage(id : number){

        if (id == null || id > this.pageMax || id == 0 ){
        this.erreur=true;

    }else{
        this.pageIndex = id;            
    }
}
public poppup(){

    var popup = document.getElementById("choice-page");
    popup.classList.toggle("choice-page");
}
```

And the css:

```
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .choice-page {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

So my problem is with the html as I am not able to display the popup.